# How to serialize type property for object value in map?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I need some help. I must get next json:

```
{
  "433434" : {
    "type" : "MULTIPLE",
    "value" : [ {
      "type" : "NUMBER",
      "value" : 322332
    }, {
      "type" : "NUMBER",
      "value" : 322332
    } ]
  }
}
```

But I have this:

```
{
  "433434" : {
    "value" : [ {
      "type" : "NUMBER",
      "value" : 322332
    }, {
      "type" : "NUMBER",
      "value" : 322332
    } ]
  }
}
```

I am using Jackson. Its my main class

```
package com.un1acker;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.un1acker.characteristic.AbstractCharacteristic;
import com.un1acker.characteristic.MultipleCharacteristic;
import com.un1acker.characteristic.NumCharacteristic;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        NumCharacteristic numCharacteristic = new NumCharacteristic();
        numCharacteristic.setValue(BigInteger.valueOf(322332L));
        List<AbstractCharacteristic<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(numCharacteristic);
        list.add(numCharacteristic);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        MultipleCharacteristic multipleCharacteristic = new MultipleCharacteristic();
        multipleCharacteristic.setValue(list);
        Map<String, AbstractCharacteristic<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("433434", multipleCharacteristic);
        mapper.writeValue(sw, map);

        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

And I have class MultipleCharateristic and NumberCharacteristic who extends from AbstractCharacteristic. Planned that we have map>, that contains in value MultipleCharacteristic. 
In the MultipleCharacteristic set list of NumberCharacteristic values.

```
package com.un1acker.characteristic;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({     @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = NumCharacteristic.class,
        name = "NUMBER"
), @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = MultipleCharacteristic.class,
        name = "MULTIPLE")})
public abstract class  AbstractCharacteristic<T>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6524899961842198462L;
    private T value;

    public AbstractCharacteristic() {
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    protected void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

NumCharacteristic Class

```
package com.un1acker.characteristic;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class NumCharacteristic extends AbstractCharacteristic<BigInteger> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9220460768952701281L;

    public NumCharacteristic() {
    }
    public void setValue(BigInteger value) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

MultipleCharacteristic class

```
package com.un1acker.characteristic;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.un1acker.MyCustomSerializer;

import java.util.List;
public class MultipleCharacteristic extends AbstractCharacteristic<List<? extends AbstractCharacteristic<?>>> {
    @Override
    public void setValue(List<? extends AbstractCharacteristic<?>> value) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)

    public List<? extends AbstractCharacteristic<?>> getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }
}
```

I tried create custom serialize for the MultipleClass with override method serializeWithType but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me: Add custom serializer for `MultipleCharacteristic`:

```
public class MultipleCharacteristicValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MultipleCharacteristic> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MultipleCharacteristic multipleCharacteristicValue, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("value");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for (AbstractCharacteristic<?> characteristicValue : multipleCharacteristicValue.getValue()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(characteristicValue);
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(MultipleCharacteristic value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        typeSer.writeTypePrefixForObject(value, jgen);
        serialize(value, jgen, provider);
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(value, jgen);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<MultipleCharacteristic> handledType() {
        return MultipleCharacteristic.class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a Jackson bug. Your MultipleCharacteristic type serializes fine and includes the type when on its own, but not when it's a map value, which I would expect to work the same way:

```
@Test // passes
public void serialize_multiple_characteristic() throws Exception {
    MultipleCharacteristic chr = new MultipleCharacteristic();
    chr.setValue(new ArrayList<>());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    assertThat(mapper.writeValueAsString(chr), equivalentTo("{ type: 'MULTIPLE', value: [] }"));
}

@Test // fails, got: {"xyzzy":{"value":[]}}
public void serialize_multiple_characteristic_in_map_value() throws Exception {
    MultipleCharacteristic chr = new MultipleCharacteristic();
    chr.setValue(new ArrayList<>());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, MultipleCharacteristic> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("xyzzy", chr);
    assertThat(mapper.writeValueAsString(map), equivalentTo("{ 'xyzzy': { type: 'MULTIPLE', value: [] } }"));
}
```

(looking through the innards, the BeanSerializer never gets wrapped in TypeWrappedSerializer)

This *might* not be a problem for you if the map is embedded in something as, as if Jackson knows the type parameters for the map (which it would normally get from a containing bean, for example) it seems to do the right thing:

```
@Test // passes
public void serialize_multiple_characteristic_in_map_value_using_writer() throws Exception {
    MultipleCharacteristic chr = new MultipleCharacteristic();
    chr.setValue(new ArrayList<>());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, AbstractCharacteristic<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("xyzzy", chr);
    // Hint to Jackson what types will be in the map
    TypeReference<?> mapType = new TypeReference<Map<String, AbstractCharacteristic<?>>>(){};
    assertThat(mapper.writerFor(mapType).writeValueAsString(map), equivalentTo("{ 'xyzzy': { type: 'MULTIPLE', value: [] } }"));
}
```

One workaround, if you just need to get the JSON produced and can't change the code to use ObjectWrite, is to use ObjectNode instead of Map:

```
@Test
public void serialize_multiple_characteristic_in_json_node() throws Exception {
    MultipleCharacteristic chr = new MultipleCharacteristic();
    chr.setValue(new ArrayList<>());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode node = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
    node.putPOJO("xyzzy", chr);
    assertThat(mapper.writeValueAsString(node), equivalentTo("{ 'xyzzy': { type: 'MULTIPLE', value: [] } }"));
}
```

Comment: I find decision. I am add custom serializer for MultipleCharacteristic by SimpleModule and override next methods: serialize,serializeWithType, handledType. But anywere thanks for your answer!=)